# Preserve casing in Blazor JSInterop?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-jsinterop

I have these data structures that I'm sending between an ASP.NET Core server and Javascript.
The data is sent as JSON serialized using websocket messages.

In this example the object has a parameter with the name `Text` (Uppercase `T`)

```
Server(C# object) --> System.Text...JsonSerialize --> WebSocket --> JSON.parse --> JS object
```

Final JS object:

```
{
  "Text": "Hello"
}
```

After introducing Blazor WebAssembly which talks directly to the server using ClientWebSocket

```
Server(C# object) --> System.Text...Serialize --> WebSocket --> System.Text...Deserialize --> C# object
```

**The problem, and my question comes with JSInterop.**

```
Blazor --> JSInterop --> JavaScript
```

Final JS object:

```
{
  "text": "Hello"
}
```

Now the `Text` property has a name `text` all in lowercase.

How can I configure the object serialization to preserve the casing from the C# objects?

## Workaround

Current workaround would be to serialize the object before passing it via JSInterop and then run JSON.parse to get back the objects.

### C#

```
var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(arg)
JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("MyFunction", jsonString);
```

### JavaScript

```
window.MyFunction = function (jsonString) {
    var arg = JSON.parse(jsonString)
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code, it's not really clear what your are asking

Comment: @aguafrommars the problem is that the C# class have Uppercase letters for the properties, but when it's send to the javascript, it's going with lower case. e.g. `class MyClass { public string Hey {get; set;} }` will become something like `{ hey: '' }`. The letter case was `Hey` but in js became `hey`. Is this what you are asking hultqvist ?

Comment: This is the default behaviour of `System.Text.Json`: see  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12685 - I had similar issues with WebAPI output when we converted to .NET Core - I changed the serializer back to NewtonSoft. There may be a way to set this in `Startup.cs` but I don't know your context

Comment: It's correct that I'm asking about the casing. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Quango I'm using Blazor client-side/webassembly. Strangely my workaround is using `System.Text.Json` as well and there the casing is preserved.

Comment: @hultqvist having the same issue. any new insights on it?

Comment: @gsharp No, I kept the workaround and try as much as possible to not pass objects via JSInterop.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `[JsonPropertyName("PropName")]` on each property,
something like this:

```
public class ClientObj
{
    [JsonPropertyName("MyProp")]
    public int MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

this stops it atm from giving camelCase properties in js.

the reason this is happening: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4283